# How to Get Selected Item On Button Click Placed Under WPF TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to achieve a very simple thing. I have created a tab control (binded with ObservableCollection) and a button on window. When i click a button it creates a new tab with a little close button under this tab. When i press this close button a button click event runs.

Now Issue is that when i press a close button it does not give the clicked/selected item so that i could remove the closed tab from the ObservableCollection.

Following is my Xaml and button Code.

Xaml:

```
<TabControl x:Name="mytabcontrol" ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" Margin="10,66,36,10"> <!--SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDetail, Mode=TwoWay}"-->
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- Tab item header: -->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tabarea" Text="{Binding Content}" />
                        <Button Content="X" Click="Button_Click" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- Tab item content goes here. -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
        <Button Content="Click here" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
```

Code Button.

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Here i need the clicked or selected item when prssing close button
            TabItem ti = mytabcontrol.SelectedItem as TabItem; //Here i want to get the selected item when click on close button from tabcontrol, but it gives null.
            MessageBox.Show(ti.Header.ToString());//Iam getting null here
        }
```

Please anyone help to get the selected item when pressing on close button under tab. In my attached project simply click on close button under tab and view the clicked button behavior, thanks

[Download Project](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=3C97297B44990FBF&resid=3C97297B44990FBF%21146&authkey=ANUxvV9m7LpImmQ)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `TabItems` contains your Object and not TabItem ones. So `mytabcontrol.SelectedItem` will be your Object type and you can't cast them to TabItem. Cast them to your Object type.

Comment: It's simple, cast mytabcontrol.SelectedItem as YourObject; Let's try.

Comment: Thankyou for reply. But the value is null so how can i cast it?. If you have any sample code then please share

Comment: You are getting null because mytabcontrol.SelectedItem as TabItem; give you null. I haven't code to share, is only one line, you had to change mytabcontrol.SelectedItem as TabItem in mytabcontrol.SelectedItem as YourObject where YourObject is the object type that you have in your list

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am new and struggling hard to learn WPF, anyway i have achieved by using this line of code(var ab  =  ((Button)sender).DataContext as clsTabs). clsTabs is my class. I just need to understand this line, that how it understands that i have clicked on button and then it extracts exactly the same item which i am trying to get. and what does it mean(DataContext as clsTabs) thanks.